# My React state variables are empty in callback when a solidity event gets fired

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, ethereum, solidity, truffle

I am using `react` with `truffle/ganache`. I have defined some events in my smart contract that fire when certain things happen. I have a react component dedicated to handling the contract instance and its events. Here's a trimmed down version that shows the issue I am having...

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import Client from '../build/contracts/Client.json'

const ClientBugDemo = (props) => {

    /**
     * props contains... 
     * contractAddress
     * web3
     */

    const [contractAddress, setContractAddress] = useState(0);
    useEffect(()=>{},[contractAddress]);

    const [contractInstance, setContractInstance] = useState(0);
    useEffect(()=>{},[contractInstance]);

    const [name, setName] = useState("");
    useEffect(()=>{},[name]);

    function _getContractInstance(address, web3){
        var instance = new web3.eth.Contract(
            Client.abi,
            address,
        );
        return instance;
    }

    if (contractAddress === 0){
        if (props.contractAddress){
            setContractAddress(props.contractAddress);

            var instance = _getContractInstance(props.contractAddress, props.web3);
            setContractInstance(instance);

            instance.events.MyCustomEvent(ev_MyCustomEventHandler);

            instance.methods.getName()
            .call()
            .then((_name, err)=>{
                if (err){
                    console.log("error : ", err);
                }
                else {
                    setName(_name);
                }
            });
    
        }
    }

    function ev_MyCustomEventHandler(error, event){
        console.log("Why is my contract Instance empty? ", contractInstance);
        console.log("But my props are fine? ", props.contractAddress);
    }
    
    return (
        <div>
            <div>Contract Address = {contractAddress}</div>
            <div>Name = {name}</div>
            <div>Have Contract = {contractInstance?"Yes":"No"}</div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ClientBugDemo;
```

I create one of the above components for my Client contract and give it a valid `contractAddress` and `web3` object.

It successfully loads and shows the contract address, name and I can see the contract instance is valid. All is good and I have a working component.

```
Contract Address = 0x64cCa2C98c13bB06e7D5b35Ae3af03B4A4C4ec71
Name = Taylor
Have Contract = Yes
```

Then the custom event fires and the handler `ev_MyCustomEventHandler` gets called as expected.

The problem is that my local `contractAddress` value is zero during that function call. In fact, as far as I can tell, all my local state variables in React are in their empty state as though the component is being re-rendered. However `props` has its original values.

So my console log shows

```
Why is my contract Instance empty? 0
But my props are fine? 0x64cCa2C98c13bB06e7D5b35Ae3af03B4A4C4ec71
```

I have tried myriad things including refactoring components thinking that maybe the state is somehow persisted when the Event handler is assigned. I really can't get this to work.

Comment: I would also guess that the value is persisted when the handler is assigned. You could try to call `ev_MyCustomEventHandler` manually before return and see if that instance of the function works as intended.

Comment: When you call the `useState` setter, the values aren't updated until control returns to the event loop. If your customer event is triggering before that occurs, the values will be stale.

Comment: @Dave the fact that I get the other state variables in the rendered display proves that they are not stale. There is a long gap between the component rendering and the event firing from the solidity contract - which happens asynchronously in response to completely different activity in other UI. So I have two reasons to believe that it's not just the timing gap of waiting for `useState` to catch up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so MUCH research on closures and such in React Hooks led me to this solution...

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import Client from '../build/contracts/Client.json'

const ClientBugDemo = (props) => {

    /**
     * props contains... 
     * contractAddress
     * web3
     */

    const [contractAddress, setContractAddress] = useState(0);
    useEffect(()=>{},[contractAddress]);

    const [contractInstance, setContractInstance] = useState(0);
    useEffect(()=>{},[contractInstance]);

    const [name, setName] = useState("");
    useEffect(()=>{},[name]);

    const [semaphore, setSemaphore] = useState(0);
    useEffect(()=>{

        console.log("Now my Contract Instance is not empty ", contractInstance);
        if (sempahore !== 0){
            // I can do what I need to do in response to the event being called
            contractInstance.methods.doSomethingFunky()
            .call()
            .then((_funky, err)=>{
                console.log("got something funky ", _funky);
            })

            // reset the state of the "mutex" so we don't come in here endlessly
            setSemaphore(0);
        }

    },[semaphore, contractInstance]);


    function _getContractInstance(address, web3){
        var instance = new web3.eth.Contract(
            Client.abi,
            address,
        );
        return instance;
    }

    if (contractAddress === 0){
        if (props.contractAddress){
            setContractAddress(props.contractAddress);
            var instance = _getContractInstance(props.contractAddress, props.web3);
            setContractInstance(instance);
            instance.events.MyCustomEvent(ev_MyCustomEventHandler);

            instance.methods.getName()
            .call()
            .then((_name, err)=>{
                if (err){
                    console.log("error : ", err);
                }
                else {
                    setName(_name);
                }
            });
    
        }
    }

    function ev_MyCustomEventHandler(error, event){
        if (!error) setSemaphore(event);
    }
    
    return (
        <div>
            <div>Contract Address = {contractAddress}</div>
            <div>Name = {name}</div>
            <div>Have Contract = {contractInstance?"Yes":"No"}</div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ClientBugDemo;
```

What I *think* is happening is that the callback I get in response to the solidity event is run as an independent code fragment. React has no idea about any dependencies it has.

My solution was to add a sort of `semaphore` variable which could be watched in response to the event arriving. When the callback fires I set the value of that `semaphore` to contain the event value and then defer back to React Hooks.

If I use `useEffect` to give the `semaphore` a dependency on my `contractInstance`, by including it in the `useEffect` definition, then the code that executes in the `useEffect` has access to the state variable and it works.

I'm going to keep looking for a more elegant solution, because I admit this feels like a work-round, but for now this is a pattern I can repeat without having a lot of duplicate code or absolutely all my code embedded in nested `useEffect` anonymous functions.